# How to get all button types of a window?

Tags: c++, qt

Is possible to retrieve all button types of a window?
I'm trying to written a function like this:

```
...

for (const auto* but : list)
{
    qDebug() << "   " << but->objectName();

    if (QToolButton* tbn = qobject_cast<QToolButton*>(but))
    {
        connect(but, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(toolButton_pressed()));
        connect(but, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(toolButton_released()));
    }
    else if (QPushButton* pbn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(but))
    {
        connect(but, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(pushButton_pressed()));
        connect(but, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(pushButton_released()));
    }
}
```

I know only how to get a specific button type:

`QList<QToolButton*> list = this->findChildren<QToolButton*>();`

Comment: I believe this would work: `QList<QAbstractButton*> list = this->findChildren<QAbstractButton *>();` The `QAbstractButton` class is the base of all buttons.

Comment: Obligatory note: do not use legacy `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, use the new syntax.

Comment: @hyde whats the new syntax?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax , and also in this case "new" means 10 year old.